# How to manipulate field with Number of value "unlimited" through php

Tags: 7, views, theming, entities

I've got a field image with unlimited number of value and a view who shows 12 of them from different node(in this case I can not use delta).
Now instead of showing the 8th and the 11th pictures I want to show a blank box with text.

I would like to insert this loop so I installed view PHP and I wrote this code on the box "Output code"

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($row->field_image as $image){
  if ($counter++ = 8){
  echo "something";
continue;
}
  if ($counter++ = 11){
  echo "something else";
continue;
}
print $images;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?
How can I get the result I want?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.
I was trying to output 12 images from different contents. Each contents has got more than one image using one image field with number of value "unlimited".
I was trying using View PHP module and adding something like this

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($row->field_image as $image){
  if ($counter++ == 8){
  echo "something";
continue;
}
  if ($counter++ == 11){
  echo "something else";
continue;
}
print $images;
}
```

But I was getting just numbers 1 and 2 (probably the node id, I've got just two nodes for the moment.)

I start to go around the web with no result so I've started to play around with fields and the view theme (views-view-unformatted--portfolio--page-2.tpl.php).
I found one problem there, each group of images of one node was in one row but I should have one image per row, does not matter if they were from the same content (I've got random sort criteria). So I went into the view, I clicked on the image field and under "Multiple field settings" I dunchecked "Display all values in the same row " so I could get them in different rows. I edited the views-view-unformatted--portfolio--page-2.tpl.php in this way

```
<?php 
$counter = 0;
 foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
 $counter++;
 print '<div class="'.$classes_array[$id].'">';
 if ($counter == 8) {
   print 'Something';
 } elseif ($counter == 11) {
   print 'Something else';
 } else {
  print $row;
  }
  print '</div>';
  }
  ?>
```

Here we go. I've got the thing I wanted without using the View PHP.
Thanks to David Meister for suggesting me to put the $counter++ outside the if statement, it works much much better.

Answer (score 1):

Those if($counter++ = 8) lines look whacky to me.

don't you mean:

```
$counter++;
if( $counter == 8 ) {
  /* do stuff */
}
```

checking for equality is == or === not =

Comment: Hi David, sorry it was my mistake, in my code it was == instead of = . Anyway my question was about the manipulation of the field with unlimited number of value. Your way to use the $counter++ outside the if statemants works better and it helped me. Thanks a lot. Anyway I will add the solution.